# Flask through CGI on server gives EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: python, flask, cgi

I am trying to host a Flask application on a Linux farm, using a .cgi file to run that Flask application.
In my .cgi file i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from index import app

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

and in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/username/public_html/cgi-bin/index.cgi/$1 [L]
```

.htaccess is in /public_html and index.cgi is in /public_html/cgi-bin
My Flask app runs on host='0.0.0.0' so that I could access it, however when I try to access my page, my browser throws me ERR.EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I even tried a simple .cgi file like the one below, but still EMPTY_RESPONSE

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def fnord():
    return "hello"

CGIHandler().run(app)
```